# Expand 2^(k + 1)

Tags: math, algebra

http://doyourmath.com/web-algebrator/#c=expand_algexpand&v5=2%5E(k%2B1)

Anyone can explain why does expand 2^(k + 1) equal to (2^k) + 1?

Comment: What programming language are you using? What code you have written so far? What difficulties did you encounter with your code? If you are unable to answer those questions this is a very strong indication that you shouldn't be asking here.

Comment: It should be (2^k)(2^1), no?

Comment: I confuse on the algebra part in the proof by induction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not actually possible.  2^(k+1) is always going to be an even number.  2^k + 1 is always going to be an odd number.

I think you mean

```
2^(k+1) = 2^k * 2^1 = 2^k * 2.
```

One way of looking at it is the associative property of multiplication:

```
(2 X 3) X 4 = 2 X (3 X 4)
```

No matter how you group the numbers, the outcome will always be equal.  In this case we're dealing with exponents, which is a shorthand notation for multiplying a number by itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is not!!!

`2^(k+1) = 2^k * 2` which is greater than `2^k + 1`

Instead `(k+1)^2` expands to `(k^2)+2k+1`

http://doyourmath.com/web-algebrator/#c=expand_algexpand&v5=2%5E(k%2B1) has ERRORS!

Comment: Any code you have written?